# What is the SOLR query i need to make to get counts on all of the single letter names in my system?

Tags: solr

I am expecting counts on all the single letter names such as:

```
A:10
B:20
C:5
D:13
E:2
...
```

Most names in my system are not single letters... but I want to know how many are. I am using the following syntax with a wildcard:

`?rows=0&start=0&q=name:/?/&facet=true&facet.field=name`

I get 0 results. Rows=0 because I don't actually want to see any results. However when i use:

`?rows=0&start=0&q=name:A&facet=true&facet.field=name`

I get a count of 1600 for 'A'.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with my wildcard query?

I'm on Solr 7.

Comment: /./ also does not work

Comment: If the field is tokenized, you'll get all named that have a single letter somewhere inside it - queries runs against the generated tokens, not the stored text.

Comment: Ah, ok, looks like i wont be able to get results without changing my schema.

Comment: Using a `string` field or a `KeywordTokenizer` with just a lowercase filter will probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It will match string length 1

```
 ?rows=0&start=0&q=name:/.{1}/&facet=true&facet.field=name
```